# Sum visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

After applied the advance filter, I sum only the visible cells by using the code below and it functions well. However, it shows error when there is no visible cell after the filter. Any idea on how to cover the error?

```
Sub sum ()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    x = cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Tax Invoice").Range("M55") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H7:H" & x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
End sub
```

Comment: What does the error specifically say? What line does it occur on? I can't seem to reproduce this myself.

Comment: Hi @SCB, Paul has answered it as shown below. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of visible rows before attempting to calculate the sum:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sumTaxInvRng()
    Dim x As Long, vRng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
        Set vRng = .Range("H7:H" & x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    If vRng.Count > vRng.Columns.Count Then
        Sheets("Tax Invoice").Range("M55") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vRng)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Also, you should not use a native function name for your functions: <strike>`Sub sum()`</strike>