# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) also includes hidden/filtered cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that I'm using a filter on.  I simply want to calculate the total values in column N, that are visible.  The data starts in row 2, and ends at row 2047.

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556476/4650297) but it gives me the same type of issue I'm having.

Here's my function:

```
Function sumVisible() As String
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("N2:N2047").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' Debug.Print "Range: " & rng.Address & ", Sum: " & WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
sumVisible = Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng), "$#,###.##")
End Function
```

With my current filter, my header row (1) is visible, as are rows 901 to 937.  So, I want to sum N901:N937.

However, the `rng` keeps getting set to `$N$2:$N$2047`.  I expected it to be `$N$901:$N$937`.

Using the function that is given to the thread I linked to above, I get a range of `$N$2:$N$937`...so at the very least, I'm getting the *end* row correctly, but not the start row.

*But!* if I type `Range("N2:N2047").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` in the Immediate Window, outside of a macro, it correctly selects just the visible cells.  And one step further, doing `?Range("N2:N2047").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).address` correctly returns `$N$901:$N$937`.

What may be going wrong?

Edit: I just found that doing `=SUBTOTAL(9,N1:N2047)` will just sum the visible cells, so I'm using that.  But my question still stands - why isn't `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` working correctly in the macro?

Comment: The function works correctly for me.  How have you hidden the rows that you don't want included?  (Maybe there is something funny in the way that is being done that means Excel isn't thinking that `.Hidden` is `True`.)

Comment: @YowE3K - I'm simply using a filter.  I have data in columns, and I'm filtering out the data based on a column.  I have row `2` filtered out, and doing `?Rows(2).Hidden` in the Immediate Window correctly returned `True`.  I don't have any `Worksheet_Change` type events either, the only macro is the one I am asking about.

Comment: I tried manually hiding rows, and using a Filter to hide the rows.  Both methods seem to work as expected.

Comment: @YowE3K - It looks like I had my column N formatted as `General`. I change to `Number` and now it's working as expected.  Yay!  ...but I'm still left wondering, why does the format matter? What if I had text there and wanted to do something with the text? Why should the format matter for VBA if I just want visible cells? Or is it just a quirk of VBA?

Comment: My testing was done without any formatting being applied to cells (i.e. using `General`), and it worked.  Try running your function in a completely new workbook with some dummy data.  See if that works.  Then try it in a new worksheet in your existing workbook.  Then try it in another column of the existing worksheet.

Comment: @YowE3K - Very odd. I did the steps, and they worked correctly in a new book, in a new sheet, and another column. After adjusting the type in `N`, it seems to work now without issue.  A note, I've been adding data to this workbook over some time, so perhaps doing so created various `Types` and that was causing some weirdness?  In any case, I don't know what the "answer" is to how to fix, but it looks like forcing a type did the trick.  :/

Comment: Does that mean we have to close the question as "cannot be reproduced"? :D

Comment: @YowE3K - Haha, yeah I suppose it does.  What's the etiquette for that, should I delete this question? Or get it closed as "Can't reproduce"?  I think close, so people may see this in the future, and at least check the format type before posting?

Comment: Should we ping Emily Post to ask re etiquette?

Comment: @YowE3K - Yeah, that or perhaps I could post the question on meta? (Is it an appropriate question for meta?).  I'm down for whatever is best for the SE Community :)

Comment: Meta sounds a good idea.  But only if this situation is reproducible ;) (And only if it hasn't already been asked.  I always find it hard to work out what has, and hasn't, already been asked on SO and SOM.  Oops - MSO, not SOM - I just saw that the current hot meta post is "why is meta at the beginning of Meta SO" - very good timing!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your `rng` with the line below:

```
Set rng = Range("N2:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Later using your debug line `Debug.Print rng.Address`, I get the following range in the immediate window:

```
$N$901:$N$937
```

Comment: Hm, good idea, but I'm still getting `$N$2:$N$937`.  Could it somehow be the data ...? I'm not doing much, literally just filtering on one column, and nothing "fancy".  I've even fully qualified the range to make positive it's running on `Sheet1`. Is there more info. I could give? I could, of course, post some sample data, but I have a feeling it's more to do with my WB than the data itself.

Comment: @BruceWayne  it's somehow related to your data , or structure , I ran several tests with different filtered ranges, and the results came good. What type of Format you have in column J ?

Comment: Column J is formatted as `Number`.  Column N was `General`, but they are actually numbers. Let me format those as Number and try again.  Edit: Aha, I changed column N to `Number` and it looks like it's working. ...that's odd though. Why wouldn't it work with `General`?