# How to fix copying and pasting visible cells based on selected variable(s) in VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies info only related to a customer we select in reportsheet  (through data validation option - based on customer name), and then pastes all the info (without the headers) linked to this customer from datasheet to copysheet.

The datasheet contains data from the whole year but we're only intereseted in the recent days **so I filter on the date column and position on the first active cell after A1 cell** (e.g. at A1556). Works well - it copies data from  the customer we've selected and creates a report. The only PROBLEM : I want to copy only data from VISIBLE CELLS, but when I exclude (filter) another variable (e.g. exclude one of the address) linked to the selected customer and which  was located after the first visible cell (i.e. A1558 in this case) the macro will still copy all the data linked to the selected customer from the first active cell where we positioned the cell (A1556 cell in this case).

I've tried to use the PasteSpecial Paste:=xlCellTypeVisible  to select only visible cells but it copies all the data related to the customer we've selected after the active cell. Even the data excluded via filter options.

```
Set erange = Sheet3.Range("A2:B60") ' email range for a given customer
Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set reportsheet = Sheet2
Set copysheet = Sheet5


customer = reportsheet.Range("A1").Value  'picks up the name of the client
edress = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(customer, erange, 2, False)

reportsheet.Range("B1").Value = edress
copysheet.Range("A2:N1000").Clear  ' clears data from sheet5 
reportsheet.Range("A2:N1000").ClearContents 'clears data from sheet2 

datasheet.Select 'sheet1

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = ActiveCell.Row To finalrow
If Cells(i, 5) = customer Then  
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 14)).Copy 
copysheet.Select 'selcts sheet5 to copy the data
Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlCellTypeVisible  
Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats 
datasheet.Select

  End If
Next i

copysheet.Select
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
```

I expect the macro to copy only the visible cells of the selected customer from the visible cells only (exlcuding header). Not to include the excluded cells- even if they are from the same customer.

Comment: `xlCellTypeVisible` is part of the `SpecialCells` method and is used in the copy stage, not in `PasteSpecial`.  Here is the answer to a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351729/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-also-includes-hidden-filtered-cells.  Also, you should avoid using `Select`.  There is no need, just define your ranges `Sheet1.Range("A1")`, etc.