# vba Find function with many filtered data - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with data about 30.000 rows and 5 columns. The first row of data is the 12th row, where column names are.
Cells in Range("A1:A10") are used for set of string parameters.

I am using method:

```
Sub FindString(aString As String)

Dim RangeResult As Range

Set RangeResult = Range("A1:A10").Find(What:=aString)

RangeResult.Select

End Sub
```

that works fine when calling

```
FindString aString:="Type"
```

But when I have an active filter on my data that remains only (let's say) 100 rows visible, I am receiving an error ***Object variable or With block variable not set***. It is caused by that fact that ***RangeResult = Nothing*** when debugging.

I have to say that the target parameter is always present in Cell A2. So the only difference is when calling with/without filtered data.

It would be nice if you could help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

*EDIT (when solved): The issue is related with the fact that cell A2 becomes hidden*

Comment: You need to specify the other parameters of `Find`. I'm guessing `LookIn:=xlFormulas` and `LookAt:=xlWhole`. Then, it's still good practice to test `If Not RangeResult Is Nothing` before attempting to use it further.

Comment: Actually, I am using it with more parameters - ***Find(What:=aString, After:=aAfter, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)*** I wrote it simplified to show that the problem is really in filtering data

Comment: `Range("A1:A10")` is always A1:A10, regardless of what actual row number is the first visible on the screen. Please note the row numbers on the left, those are the ones you need to use. Or use [SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42351729/11683).

Comment: I know the Range is always the same, regardless my filtered data. That' s the reason why I can not understand what the real problem is and how to solve it

Comment: I think you have it exactly backwards. A1:A10 is always A1:A10, whether it's visible or not. If the first visible row is A1 (your table header) and the second visible row is A300, then it's A300, not A2.

Comment: You still need to specify `LookIn`, as recommended in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: My table starts at row 12 and filter is applied on this row. Cells A1:A10 are used for parameters

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `LookIn:=xlFormulas` did not help. It worked without filtered data, but with filtered data it brought the same error. So that's not the reason

Comment: I've seen the `Find` method using `xlFormulas` fail when using `AutoFilter`, so I don't use it when the latter is applied. But that's a new one, you're saying that `A1:A10` is outside of the filter. I've replicated this and "Type" gets found every time I run `FindString "Type"`. Could you share the complete code where your function is being called?

Comment: @VBasic2008 : how many rows of data did you use? I've forget to mention that it works when I use filter on smaller type of table, like 10 rows. Problem is with my real 30ths of rows

Comment: Without additional information including the code it is hard to help. We don't know which worksheet is active at the time. Maybe you should write your procedure with an additional worksheet argument. You could create a new workbook and try to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### AutoFilter Embarrassing the Find Method

- In the end I could produce your problem in two cases:

  1. The wrong worksheet was active.
  2. After applying a filter using `AutoFilter` and Row 2 was hidden ("Type" was in `A2`).
- The first case is considered in all three solutions.
- The second case still affects the `Find` method solution.
- 'Luckily', there are other solutions, e.g. `Application.Match` and the 'good old' `For Each Next` loop (it's only 10 cells).
- To conclude, the `Find` method doesn't 'like' `AutoFilter`, but then `AutoFilter` 'likes' to be in the first row.
- An interesting issue to see how `AutoFilter` 'likes' the first row, is when a filter is applied and you try to unhide any hidden rows above it. You cannot do it before you haven't removed the filter e.g. used `ShowAllData`. The same applies to rows below the filtered range, so one might conclude that `AutoFilter` 'reserves the rights' on rows: 'No row gets unhidden while my data is filtered'.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Still 'buggy'.
Sub findString(aWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal aString As String)
    If Not aWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        With aWorksheet.Range("A1:A10")
            Dim cel As Range
             ' ".Cells(10)" ensures the first occurrence from "A1".
             ' "xlFormulas" covers hidden rows.
            Set cel = .Find(What:=aString, After:=.Cells(10), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                .Worksheet.Activate
                cel.Select
                'Debug.Print Selection.Address
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub TESTfindString()
    findString Sheet1, "Type"
End Sub

Sub matchString(aWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal aString As String)
    If Not aWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = aWorksheet.Range("A1:A10")
        Dim idx As Variant
        ' Case-insensitive: A=a
        ' If you need A<>a, you can set "Option Compare 1" (or "TextCompare")
        idx = Application.Match(aString, rng, 0)
        If Not IsError(idx) Then
            aWorksheet.Activate
            rng(idx).Select
            'Debug.Print Selection.Address
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub TESTmatchString()
    matchString Sheet1, "Type"
End Sub

Sub loopString(aWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal aString As String)
    If Not aWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = aWorksheet.Range("A1:A10")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 10
            ' Case-sensitive: "A<>a".
            If rng(i).Value = aString Then
            ' If you need "A=a" then use this instead:
            'If StrComp(rng(i).Value, aString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                aWorksheet.Activate
                rng(i).Select
                'Debug.Print Selection.Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub TESTloopString()
    loopString Sheet1, "Type"
End Sub
```

Comment: You were right, the problem was not the amount of data but the fact the "menu" rows become suddenly hidden. Using `Match` function solved the issue. Thanks a lot, you did a great investigating job with a offer of working solutions