# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Returns Hidden cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeing the problem identified in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351729/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-also-includes-hidden-filtered-cells) from 2017, but there's not a suitable answer.

Note I am using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20644) 64-bit

I have a ListObject to which a date filter is applied "After 12/31/2007". I also tried "unchecking" the boxes for prior years in the Autofilter drop down but get the same results.

I wrote a function to echo the values of only the visible rows in a particular column that includes this logic:

```
    Set oAll = Sheet2.ListObjects(1).Range
    iCol = Sheet2.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(ColName).Index
    On Error Resume Next
        Set oVisRng = oAll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not oVisRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each oArea In oVisRng.Areas
            For Each oRng In oArea.Rows
            {do stuff}
            Next oRng
        Next oArea
    End if
```

I added a watch for `Sheet2.ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address`, that shows only the visible cells *until* the code executes and it shows the entire range including the filtered rows... and it remains the entire range after the code terminates.

I've used similar logic lots of times over many years, but this is the first I've encountered this behavior. I've tried different combos/permutations of range variables (e.g., only the list column, using `.DataBodyRange`, yadda, yadda), with no success. I'm stumped. Every time, oVisRng returns the entire Sheet2.ListObjects(1).Range.

Comment: Not sure if that's all your code, but if there's any chance `oVisRng` was already referencing a range, you should set it to Nothing before calling `SpecialCells`...

Comment: Only declarations omitted. If/when I loop things I set the object to nothing, but that does not apply in this case. Appreciate the comment, regardless.

Comment: What if you loop over the rows in the table and check the `Hidden` property - does that also not reflect the filtering?

Comment: try `For Each oArea In oAll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yes, it does and I've resorted to that process until I get this figured out. I added `If Not oRng.Hidden Then...` inside the loop.

Comment: @k1dr0ck: The SpecialCells method returns the entire range, not just the visible parts. Consequently, oArea is the same range  as oAll.